# How to avoid warning "IMP-00041: Warning: object created with compilation warnings"?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm struggling with oracle import utility.

I'm running the script below and getting compilation warning. I have written a script to recompile all the objects after the import but I hate seeing those warnings every time a do a new export and reimport it. Can anyone help me with this issue ?

```
imp user/CHANGEME/host:8081/dbname fromuser=schemaowner touser=schemauser file=exp_$TODAY.dmp  log=imp_$TODAY.log  ignore=y
```

then run scripts like

```
alter view myview1 compile; 
alter view myview2 compile; 
alter view myview3 compile;
```

Is there any attribute or workaround to say please import the parents first then import the views and triggers ect..?

Comment: Use  Datapump (`impdp` ) insted of `exp/imp` . You will get many options to handle database objects better and it also runs faster. You could also handle exceptions if any while running it as PL/SQL program, using `DBMS_DATAPUMP` package which implements the same.

Comment: impdp is not an option for me. I don't have read/write access to database folder. Also we are migrating to Dbass in the future, so it's not an option.

Comment: "Dbass" - Interesting. Is that really what it's called?

Comment: please recreate the imp warnings, then do not recompile the views,first identify why and where the views have compile errors.